# How to transform multivalues xml attribute with xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform xml to plain xml with xsl from:

```
<LongAssetInfoMulti attrTagName.s="tagName" attrName.s="tagName" values.ll="14491 14553 14568 14581 15239 15240 15241"/>
```

to:

```
<tagName>14491</tagName>
<tagName>14553</tagName> ....
```

I allready did this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="test" select="//LongAssetInfoMulti/@values.ll"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$test">
            <xsl:value-of select="$test"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Anyone have any idea how to parse multiple attribute values?

Comment: You need to *tokenize* the values. Which XSLT processor are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As michael.hor257k said we can use tokenization, like below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="http://www.courts.state.mn.us/ProtectionOrderExtension/1.0" xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0" extension-element-prefixes="ext nc" exclude-result-prefixes="mscef msxsl exsl ext">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="test" select="//LongAssetInfoMulti/@values.ll"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($test, ' ')">
            <xsl:sort select="$test"/>
            <tagname>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </tagname>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```